# How do I click a button on a webpage through VBA?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to use click a button through vba but it tells me that the "Object doesn't support this property or method".

My VBA code right now is:

```
IE.document.getElementByType("button").getelementByClass("qm_historyTab_GoButton").Click
```

The HTML for the button is:

```
<button class="qm_historyTab_GoButton" type="submit" style="font:normal 11px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans serif;">
  <span class="qm_historyTab_GoButtonText">GO</span>
</button>
```

Comment: `getElementByType` >> `getElementByTagName` and `getelementByClass("qm_historyTab_GoButton")` >> `getelementsByClassName("qm_historyTab_GoButton")(0)`

Comment: I tried using this but it didn't work. To make sure that I didn't screw it up, I am attaching my code: `IE.document.getelementByClass("qm_historyTab_GoButton")(0).Click`

Comment: `getelementByClass` is not a thing, as I pointed out in my comment.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to StackOverFlow so I didn't really understand what you meant. Does ">>" mean instead? Right now my code is: `IE.document.getelementByTagName("Button").getelementsByClassName("qm_historyTab_GoButton")(0).Click` It still gives me the same error message

Comment: Yes ">>" means "change to this" but that's just my personal shorthand and perhaps not as obvious as I'd thought...  Also, I made a typo in my comment and it should have been `getElementsByTagName`. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution in this specific instance. The button is a submit type and sends a message using HTMLInputElement.

What I needed to do was add "Microsoft HTML Object Library" to my references and utilize those features.

I had to create the variable that would send the response:

`Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement`

I couldn't figure out how to refer to this specific element individually so I grabbed everything with it's class name.

`For Each htmlInput In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("qm_historyTab_GoButton")
    If Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "submit" Then
        htmlInput.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Next htmlInput`

Then I had the program cycle through each item in the series and send a submit response. Since this was the only one with the class name, I got lucky.

So anyways, that's how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button") _
   .getelementsByClassName("qm_historyTab_GoButton")(0).Click
```

Both of the `getXXX` methods return a collection of items (even if there's only one match in the document) so to address a single item from the last one in order to click it you need to add the `(0)`

**EDIT**: if the aim is to submit the form then this will also work

```
IE.document.getElementById("qm_historyForm_7871").submit
```

or as there's only one button with that classname:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("qm_historyTab_GoButton")(0).Click
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. It tells me "Run-time error '408': Object doesn't support property or method". I am using the exact lines that you have provided. `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button") _
        .getelementsByClassName("qm_historyTab_GoButton")(0).Click` The website is https://web.tmxmoney.com/pricehistory.php?qm_symbol=CM. The button is: `<button class="qm_historyTab_GoButton" type="submit" style="font:normal 11px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans serif;"><span class="qm_historyTab_GoButtonText">GO</span></button>` It is a submit type so the click function won't work but I don't know